# How to get the stackblitz typescript package running locally?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I found a package here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/y-prosemirror-ynw2fg?file=index.ts
I have downloaded and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jljVL.png)

I ran `npm install` and the dependencies should be installed already.
But when I run `node index.ts` or `ts-node index.ts` errors show up:

```
client_8 % ts-node index.ts         

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:500
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
schema.ts:9:14 - error TS2339: Property 'ychange_user' does not exist on type '{}'.

9     domAttrs.ychange_user = attrs.ychange.user
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
schema.ts:10:14 - error TS2339: Property 'ychange_state' does not exist on type '{}'.

10     domAttrs.ychange_state = attrs.ychange.state
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
schema.ts:202:36 - error TS2322: Type '{ doc: { content: string; }; paragraph: { attrs: { ychange: { default: any; }; }; content: string; group: string; parseDOM: { tag: string; }[]; toDOM(node: any): {}[]; }; blockquote: { attrs: { ychange: { default: any; }; }; ... 4 more ...; toDOM(node: any): {}[]; }; ... 5 more ...; hard_break: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'OrderedMap<NodeSpec> | { blockquote: NodeSpec; image: NodeSpec; text: NodeSpec; doc: NodeSpec; paragraph: NodeSpec; horizontal_rule: NodeSpec; heading: NodeSpec; code_block: NodeSpec; hard_break: NodeSpec; }'.
  Type '{ doc: { content: string; }; paragraph: { attrs: { ychange: { default: any; }; }; content: string; group: string; parseDOM: { tag: string; }[]; toDOM(node: any): {}[]; }; blockquote: { attrs: { ychange: { default: any; }; }; ... 4 more ...; toDOM(node: any): {}[]; }; ... 5 more ...; hard_break: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ blockquote: NodeSpec; image: NodeSpec; text: NodeSpec; doc: NodeSpec; paragraph: NodeSpec; horizontal_rule: NodeSpec; heading: NodeSpec; code_block: NodeSpec; hard_break: NodeSpec; }'.
    Types of property 'blockquote' are incompatible.
      Type '{ attrs: { ychange: { default: any; }; }; content: string; group: string; defining: boolean; parseDOM: { tag: string; }[]; toDOM(node: any): {}[]; }' is not assignable to type 'NodeSpec'.
        Types of property 'toDOM' are incompatible.
          Type '(node: any) => {}[]' is not assignable to type '(node: ProsemirrorNode<any>) => DOMOutputSpec'.
            Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'DOMOutputSpec'.
              Property '0' is missing in type '{}[]' but required in type 'DOMOutputSpecArray'.

202 export const schema = new Schema({ nodes, marks })
```

I am not very expierenced with Node at all.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found out how it was done.

Compile the ts into js using babel first or here: https://babeljs.io/repl.

Use browserify to make your files web compatible.
`browserify index.js > bundle.js`

then include the file to your index.html.

I don't understand why node js has to have so many versions of typescript that isn't compatible with browser. Just making everyone's life more horrible.

Comment: Node isn't meant to be compatible with the browser, if that's what you're after you should try [Deno](https://deno.land/). The problem wasn't Node, it was the fact that you used `ts-node` rather than `tsc`. `ts-node` runs the code with Node, while `tsc` converts the TypeScript to browser-compatible JavaScript.